# Cors in vertx on path with query paramters

Tags: cors, vert.x, query-string

I have domainA and domainB.

domainA  send API to domainB .I want to add **Cors** ability with **Vertx** for making sure that it is my domainA that send the API.
The rest is with URL that has query params.

for example to this URL: /hello?queryParam=var.

I want to do something like this:

router.route(".../hello?queryParam=var").handler(CorsHandler.create("specificOriginDomain")

But I also have another API (in a different place in the code) with the same URL without the query parameters: ".../hello"
that I don't want to block with the Cors

how can I block(with Cors) a specific URL relates to his query parameters?

Comment: You want to use *CORS* to block a request if it has (or doesn't have) query parameters?  CORS is not the appropriate mechanism for that.  CORS is concerned with **cross-origin** requests.

Comment: Thank you, I was not clear, I have 2 domains. I want to use cors in Order to make sure it is really my website that sends the request. but I want to do this just for the request with query parameters

Comment: as @RainbowDash mentioned, CORS is not the proper solution here. CORS will help you prevent your *clients* to be tricked into cross origin related attacks but will not make sure that its only domainA that sends request to domainB. anybody can fake a origin header as simple as using tools like curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand the goal is to have `CORS` only if there is a HTTP parameter. In this case you need to write a custom handler. Here's a simple example:

```
// create the desired CORS handler to check CORS as you desire
// this handler is not be used directly but will be used 
CORSHandler cors = CORSHandler.create(...);

Handler<RoutingContext> myCORSHandler = (ctx) -> {
  if (ctx.request().getParam("var") != null) {
    // your request contains the parameter "var" so
    // we will make it go through the CORS Handler
    cors.handle(ctx);
  } else {
    // the request is "safe" so we ignore the CORS
    // and go to the next handler directly
    ctx.next();
  }
});

// later in your application, just use your CORS handler
Router app = Router.router(vertx);
...
app.route().handler(myCorsHandler);
app.route().handler(ctx -> {
  // depending in the params when you reach here, the CORS
  // have been checked or not...
  // if you want to know which case happened, just add a
  // property to the context in the "if" statement in the
  // custom handler, e.g.: ctx.put("CORS", true)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

While what you ask is technically possible, I must agree with the comment that this is not something you probably should do.

Let me try to explain. You can set up two handlers on the same route and it would work:

```java
router.get("hello").handler(CorsHandler.create("specificOriginDomain"));
router.get("hello").handler((req) -> { ... });
```

But that would apply same logic for all routes, query parameters or not.

Moreover, CORS is blocking by default. So when you specify `CorsHandler` you actually allow cross-origin requests from that domain, not the other way around. It seems that all your requests come from the same domain, though.

What I would suggest instead is to implement the logic in the handler, unrelated to CORS:

```java
router.get("hello").handler((ctx) -> { 

   if (ctx.request().getParam("var") != null) {
      ctx.fail(403);
   }
   else {
      // Continue as usual 
   }
 });
```

You can also see how `CorsHandler` is actually implemented:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/master/vertx-web/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/impl/CorsHandlerImpl.java#L162

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I was not clear, I have 2 domains. I want to use cors in Order to make sure it is really my website that sends the request. but I want to do this just for the request with query parameters

Comment: I see. You'll still have to check if there are query parameters yourself, though. `CorsHandler` can't check this.